# Are HAC robust standard errors robust against autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, garch, intercept, robust-standard-error

Suppose I have a GARCH(p,q) model with constant conditional mean,
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu + u_t, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \alpha_s u_{t-q}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dotsc + \beta_r \sigma_{t-p}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1). \\
\end{aligned}
I want to test whether $\mu=0$. I could estimate the model and examine the significance of the estimated $\hat\mu$. But as an alternative, could I regress $y_t$ on a constant and use HAC standard errors for testing the hypothesis that $\mu=0$? That is, will HAC work as it should, or is it not applicable under GARCH-type conditional variance?

Comment: Inspired by ["How to test whether a GARCH process has zero mean?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330560/how-to-test-whether-a-garch-process-has-zero-mean) but instead of "How" I am asking whether a particular method will work or not.